# Create new Metaball family

Tags: scripting, meta-objects

I'm trying to rename my metaball. If I hit f2 and rename it, the body part disappears in the viewport. If I switch to rendered mode I can see it, but not select it.
Is this a bug? How do I get around it?
Also, if I rename the metaball back to Mball, The body reappears, but in the form of the *entire* Mball family. Then when I move it, the Mball family disappears. Sort of frustrating.
The [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/editing.html#object-families) mention confusing behavior, but I'm in the same scene.

Note:
I only want to create a new family because I couldn't hide parts of it.
I'm writing a python script to render it multiple times, and each time I want the metaball to grow more blobs.
So if there's an easy (ish) way to 'hide' parts of the metaball from a script, I'd sidestep the issue.

I'm using Blender 2.83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while I figured out why it wasn't working: the name of the new family ended with a number. For instance, `MballTwo` works while `Mball2` doesn't.